# Spring Cloud Config Server - Bitbucket Session

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, bitbucket-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I’m trying to solve an awkward problem with Spring Cloud Config Server via Bitbucket.

My config repo on Bitbucket Cloud Server. **bootstrap.yaml** file looks like below.

```
server:
  port: 9101
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://****@bitbucket.org/****/config-repo.git
          username: ***
          password: ****
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          clone-on-start: true
          force-pull: true
          basedir: /tmp
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS}
    register-with-eureka: true
```

The config-server fetched all properties from bitbucket and write to the /tmp file after app is started.

There is no exception or no warning. Everything is fine.

I’m getting an error looks like below after a few hours later, the app trying to fetch from bitbucket to update all properties.

```
2020-12-22 12:08:55.865  INFO 1 --- [nio-9101-exec-5] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/tmp/salesart-spm-prod.properties

2020-12-22 12:08:56.936  WARN 1 --- [nio-9101-exec-7] .c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Could not fetch remote for master remote: https://****@bitbucket.org/***/config-repo.git
```

I guess the problem is about the Bitbucket Session. Why did I thought like this?

Because after successfully logged in to bitbucket server via username and password, the app fetching all properties.

Then, a few hours later I’m getting same error.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I know nothing of sessions. jgit doesn't do anything specific for a git provider. Can you turn on debug logging for `org.springframework.cloud.config` and see if you can find more details (maybe an exception)? What version are you using?